# Is there a way to download a specific version of Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm currently facing some issues with the latest Visual Studio 2019 version (16.7.0) and I want to go back to a previous version, specifically 16.6.2. However on the VS website I can't find a place where to download a specific version of Visual Studio, so is there a way (even non official) to download this version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Officially, Microsoft [provides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history) older installer for VS 2019, but only the Enterprise, Professional, and Build Tools. Meanwhile [Community edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/servicing)

> is only supported on the recommended latest release of the latest minor version of Visual Studio

So if you expect to be needing VS Community older version in the future, I suggest backing up the offline installer when they're released.

Comment: I guess it's time to ask my supervisor for a VS Professional license then.... By the way I don't get why they got this policy

Comment: This is their general policy since forever. Most unsupported OS/app are only available to download through MSDN. We're lucky they still provide access to the older versions of VS for trial purposes without MSDN subscription. Sure, other IDEs give their old version without payment, but old habits die hard at Microsoft.

Answer (score 5):

In case you need to install a specific version of the Community Edition you can download VS 20XX Professional Edition with the desired version and then, during installation, just select the Community Edition.

Steps:

1. Download the installer with the required version ([release history for VS2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history))
2. Open the installer and when the Workloads screen appears, close it to view the setup screen behind.
3. On the setup screen go to the "Available" tab
4. Choose the Community Edition (or the one you need...)

Answer (score 0):

you can download the older version of Visual studio 2019:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#installing-an-earlier-release

Comment: This looks like pretty much the same link as given in the [earlier answer by Martheen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63297739/10871073).

Answer (score 0):

For VS2022, the list is here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history